# how to see the css of a page in chrome, NOT IN ONE LINE

Tags: css, google-chrome

How can I see css in chrome with a prettier format. Currently what I see is like:

> input_tiny{width:50px}.input_small{width:100px}.input_medium{width:150px}.input_large{width:200px}.input_xlarge{width:250px}.input_xxlarge{width:300px}.input_full{width:100%}.input_full_wrap{display:block;padding-right:8px}::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}input{margin:0}input[type="search"]::-webkit-sear

and they are just presented IN ONE LINE! How can I make it in to multiple lines as

```
.input_tiny{
    width:50px
 }
 .input_samll{
     width:100px
 }
 ......
```

Comment: If you right click on the element you want to see and then choose the inspect element option it will bring up the css in a nice pretty format.

Comment: no . it seems to be presented in a one line format

Comment: Is this happening on multiple websites?

Comment: I think @kricket is referring to inspecting the styles applied to a DOM element, not viewing the CSS source. I don't see a way in the (horrid) Chrome Developer Tools how to pretty-print CSS.

Comment: Screen please. I don't know what you exactly mean!

Comment: there is "pretty print" button at debugguer bottom but it work only for js

Comment: @kricket for the website I am concerned, it is in one line. there're websites that are on multiple lines though

Answer (score 12):

Chromium ticket has been updated to fixed 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=163123

This is available in chrome stable now. You need to click the button with curly braces to prettify CSS (the same way you do JS)

[image: chrome devtools]

Answer (score 5):

You can copy and paste into a code beautifier.  I don't have a favorite but a couple include:

http://www.codebeautifier.com/

http://procssor.com/

Just Google for css beautifiers/prettifiers.

FYI...you can use similar tools for Javascript also.

Comment: that's a good workaround. Thanks.  some elements are missing though which I guess probably attributes to version issue.

Answer (score 4):

So there's two things you should know. You can open the chrome inspector with

Ctrl + Shift + J on windows or ⌥ + ⌘ + J on mac. Then you click the little magnifying glass on the bottom left. Now you can hover over elements of the page and click one. You will see all the css that applies on the right hand side and can even make changes and add new rules.

Another thing you should know is WHY most pages serve their css in one line. If the css served along with the site contained many whitespaces, then there is more information to transfer and it would take longer to load the page. So everyone does what you saw which is called minification.

If you just want all the css, you can also see what file is linked. Depending on the page, the CSS whill either be sitting in a  tag right along with the html or it will be in a file. You can download the css files by looking at the source code and finding the link to them (or through the chrome developer tools)

Other than that MTAdmin's answer might be what you want just to prettify the css.